# Drools Multiple Modify Statements vs. Single Modify Statement

Tags: drools

Is there any difference in the way how Drools reconsiders the new batch of rules to trigger, if I have a single modify statement versus multiple Modify Statements as shown below

```
rule "Multiple Modify Statements"
    dialect "mvel"
    when
        $m : Message( status == Message.HELLO )
    then
        modify ( $m ) { message = "Hope" };
        modify ( $m ) { status = Message.GOODBYE };
end

rule "Single Modify Statements"
    dialect "mvel"
    when
        $m : Message( status == Message.HELLO )
    then
        modify ( $m ) { message = "Never Give Up",
                       status = Message.GOODBYE };
end
```

And, is there any performance implications.

Actually, we are trying to create a excel decision table, with actions for each column, so multiple modify statements is more preferable as those can be represented by multiple columns in excel file.

Any insights highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question.

The RHS of the rules in Drools get compiled into Java classes. If you take a look at the generated classes in your example, you will see the following:

When using 2 modifies statements, the following code gets generated:

```
$m.setMessage("Hope");
update($m);
$m.setStatus(Message.GOODBYE);
update($m);
```

Now, when using a single modify statement, the generated code looks like this:

```
$m.setMessage("Hope");
$m.setStatus(Message.GOODBYE);
update($m);
```

The difference is the number of times the method `update` is invoked. This method is the one triggering the evaluation of any condition related to the `Message` class.

I would assume there is some kind of performance benefit when using a single `modify`, but I can't assure you if this benefit is noticeable or not. I guess your only option here is to prepare a benchmark test so you can measure the performance gain (if any) yourself.

Hope it helps,

Comment: If the sample rule is typical, then the change of `status` causes a change in the engine's network of pattern evaluations. +

Comment: @laune: Actually, We want to create a decision table and have many setters. We want to represent each setter as an action. Can't see how can I do that using single modify statement. Maybe what we can do is have normal setters and an update statement in the last column

Comment: This might simplify your action columns as well. - Hint: Merge the "last column" to be able to select the action for all rows by a single entry.

Comment: @laune: Sorry didn't understand your last comment.

Comment: @Nehu Perhaps "join cells" is the more popular term?